# Html Chrome no reproduce autoplay

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Por lo general me ocurre que al trabajar en Chrome las primeras veces logra cargar vídeos sin ningún inconveniente pero luego de un tiempo, ya no cargan mas los vídeos. Sólo me ocurre en Chrome, mientras que en firefox, edge, safari y opera, no hay ningún problema. ¿Alguna solución, sugerencia? Se los agradezco, Saludos cordiales.

El codigo no tiene nada de especial:

```
<video autoplay loop>
  <source src="videos/home-background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="videos/slide-background.webm" type="video/webm">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Parece ser un problema recurrente de chrome al igual que le sucede con la etiqueta de autocomplete. Has probado correr videos en formatos distintos a los que colocas en la descripción?

Comment: si, este es un problema que he visto que ha afectado a muchos sitios web

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chicos, ya encontré una solucion. Adjunto el link donde se detalla un poco mas el autoplay en google developers y otro link desde donde encontré la respuesta.

La solución es agregar inline el atributo "muted", ya que al parecer google por defecto bloquea los autoplay, sin embargo al poner el atributo muted se soluciona.

```
<video class="d-block w-100" muted autoplay loop>
 <source src="videos/background-mov.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Otras soluciones que plantean en el articulo, es utilizar webm primero en la lista, forzar el muted y autoplay por js. De todos modos, creo que con el muted basta, al menos a mi sirvió.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764876/html-5-video-autoplay-not-automatically-starting-in-chrome

Comment: a 2022 esta respuesta me sirvió para desktop; pero no asi para móviles
he visto si que las paginas que no tienen SSL si pueden reproducir video de fondo muted ¿Será restriccion de browsers? alguien ?